# How to extract multiple ec2 instance tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I would like to ask a question in line with above. The cli below works perfectly fine now I would also like to capture two other tags in addition to the 'Name' tag called 'Application' and 'Owner'. How can I change this to add Application and Owner tags to the out-put. So basically:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform, State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,StateTransitionReason,Tags[?Key=='Name'] | [0].Value]" --output table
```

What I am thinking is how do I duplicate `Tags[?Key=='Name'] | [0].Value]` to make it also pull Application and Owner so in effect `Tags[?Key=='Application'] | [0].Value]` and `Tags[?Key=='Owner'] | [0].Value]`? So that when I run the cli it pulls three different tags.

Comment: Frankly, this type of thing is hard to do where not every instance has every tag. You might be better-off with a simple Python script. What are you trying to do with the information once you retrieve it? Quite clearly, `table` output is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it on...

```
--query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Tags[?Key=='Application']|[0].Value,Tags[?Key=='Owner']|[0].Value]"
```

Comment: John,Thank you very much I tried that but it did not work. Did it work for you? below is what I did aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,StateTransitionReason,Tags[?Key=='Name'] | [0].Value], Tags[?Key=='Application'] | [0].Value, Tags[?Key=='Owner'] | [0].Value]" --output table

Comment: ok the cli below executed but returend None for the owner but I know that tag is there for all instances. --- aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,StateTransitionReason,Tags[?Key=='Name'] | [0].Value, Tags[?key=='Owner'] | [0].value]" --output table

Comment: Can  you change your query to: `aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,StateTransitionReason,Tags[?Key==\`Name\`].Value | [0],Tags[?Key==\`Owner\`].Value | [0]]' --output table`

Comment: Krishna - You are spot on by eliminating "Placement.Availability zone" and changing "Tags[?key=='Owner'] | [0].value" TO "Tags[?key=='Owner'].value | [0]" it worked. That worked like Magic. Please explain this change so I can learn I am now able to expand and add more tags I need following same routine. Many thanks to John and Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

this works also.  (those are back ticks around the key value)

--query 'Snapshots[*].{DES:Description,VOL:VolumeId,VSIZE:VolumeSize,Time:StartTime,ID:SnapshotId,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value,RP:Tags[?Key==`retention-period`]|[0].Value}'

Answer (score 0):

Fetching Custom tags are really helpful when you try to build something on top of that, like- system or Application configuration based on those, for EaaS, DEaaS, or TEaaS.
Hope this will work for you :
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform,State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,StateTransitionReason,Tags[?Key==`Application`].Value | [0], Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0],Tags[?Key==`Owner`].Value | [0]]' --output table –